# how to pass float value as query params using curl?

Tags: linux, http, curl

I have a python flask server running and the following http GET works on my browser, http://example.com/v1/api?lng=18.565810740668912&lat=-33.93153605161741 , however when I use command `curl http://example.com/v1/api?lng=18.565810740668912&lat=-33.93153605161741` it doesn't work. How to correct my query to work for curl?

Comment: pass url as a string "http:// ....."

Comment: @rsm you should add it to the answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to **pass URL as a string**.

It's because for shell a lot of characters used in URL have special meaning (ie `=` is an assignment, `&` makes command to run in background, etc). So

```
curl "http://example.com/v1/api?lng=18.565810740668912&lat=-33.93153605161741"
```

should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

To pass the query-parameters separated and let cURL build the query-string we can also use option  `-G` together with usual `-d` like

```sh
curl -G -d 'lng=18.565810740668912' -d 'lat=-33.93153605161741' http://example.com/v1/api
```

See also: [Construct a Query String (TLDR: Use -G argument)](https://catonmat.net/cookbooks/curl/construct-query-string)